# ereg_replace to preg_replace and OpenX

Tags: php, preg-replace, openx, ereg-replace

I have a client who is running OpenX (formerly PHPAdsNew), which is no longer being developed, and is not compatible with newer versions of PHP (as ereg and its variants are depreciated); the issue here is that I can't really tell what the ereg is supposed to be replacing to rewrite the line.

The old code is:

```
define ('phpAds_path', ereg_replace("[/\\\\]admin[/\\\\][^/\\\\]+$", '', __FILE__));
```

I would be very greatful for anyone's ideas!

Answer (score 0):

Just add delimiters around the regex:

```
ereg_replace("[/\\\\]admin[/\\\\][^/\\\\]+$", '', __FILE__)
```

becomes:

```
preg_replace("~[/\\\\]admin[/\\\\][^/\\\\]+$~", '', __FILE__)
//     here __^                  and here __^
```

Comment: I've tried that, it doesn't parse the URL.; I think it removes the admin bit from the URL, but I have no clue what the last section of the regex is for.

Comment: @JamesCorthell: Your regex maches: a slash (or backslash) then the literal 'admin' then a slash (or backslash) then anything that is not a slash  (or backslash) until the end of the string.